# Sagepay Protocol 3.00 - BasketXML Format - Discounts

Tags: xml, opayo

I'm trying to create a BasketXML entry with the following XML for the SagePay 3.00 protocol. But I keep getting the "3021: The Basket format is invalid" error.

Here's my XML:

```
<basket>
    <item>
        <description>Product desc here</description>
        <productSku>AWAL02</productSku>
        <productCode>AWAL02</productCode>
        <quantity>2</quantity>
        <unitNetAmount>22.00</unitNetAmount>
        <unitTaxAmount>0.00</unitTaxAmount>
        <unitGrossAmount>22.00</unitGrossAmount>
        <totalGrossAmount>44.00</totalGrossAmount>
    </item>

    <deliveryNetAmount>10.00</deliveryNetAmount>
    <deliveryTaxAmount>0.00</deliveryTaxAmount>
    <deliveryGrossAmount>10.00</deliveryGrossAmount>

    <discounts>
        <discount>
            <fixed>5.40</fixed>
            <description>Voucher: PB test</description>
        </discount>
    </discounts>
</basket>
```

Any one got any ideas why this is invalid? I'm also supplying the total transaction amount as:

**48.60**

in the POST for transactionRegistration.

Any ideas why its an invalid basket?

Many thanks,

Peter

Comment: How are you sending the Basket XML to the server?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved:

It turns out that actually the  being sent included some html characters. Even though they were correctly encoded, eg:

```
This is &lt;b&gt;bold&lt;/b&gt;
```

Anyway - stripping tags before submitting the basket seems to have done the trick.

The documentation does tell me that some of those characters aren't accepted by SagePay (even though valid xml). My bad.

(And apologies that the example code didn't correctly reproduce the issue).